# View Controllers in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

When you instantiate a new view controller is it faster to create the objects present within, in code like `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` and `[self.view addSubView:]` or by loading them from a nib/xib file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier the first way was definitely faster, but with iOS 4 and UINib caching it depends on how often do you hit the cache.